# How to use generics and factory design to instantiate PageObject classes

Tags: c#, selenium, generics, factory, pageobjects

I am developing a selenium framework in c#. The page classes are instantiated using a factory design to hide the instantiation logic and I would like to be able to instantiate the class using
`var myPageClass = HelperSelenium.Instance(MyPageClass)` instead of `var myPageClass = MyPageClass.Instance(driver)`

I've tried creating a generic function in HelperSelenium class, but I am not able to fully understand how generics work yet.

PageObject class example (notice I use Instance method to instantiate the class

```cs
public class HomePage : BasePage
{       
    private HomePage(IWebDriver driver, CountryEnum enum) : base(driver) { }

    private static HomePage homePage { get; set; }

    public static HomePage Instance(IWebDriver driver, CountryEnum enum)
    {
        switch (enum)
        {
             case CountryEnum.Sweden:
                 HomePage = new HomePage_SWE(driver);
                 break;
             case CountryEnum.Germany:
                 HomePage = new HomePage_GER(driver);
                 break;
             case CountryEnum.Italy:
                 HomePage = new HomePage_ITA(driver);
                 break;
             default:
                 HomePage = new HomePage_UK(driver);
                 break;
        }

        return homePage;
    }

...
}
```

```cs
public T InstancePage<T>() where T : BasePage
{
    return (T).Instance(WebDriver, CountryEnum.Sweden);
}
```

```
Error   CS0119  'T' is a type, which is not valid in the given context  InfrastructureSelenium  C:\testSelenium\Infrastructure\Helper\HelperSelenium.cs 140 Active
```

```
Error   CS0119  'T' is a type parameter, which is not valid in the given context    InfrastructureSelenium  C:\testSelenium\Infrastructure\Helper\HelperSelenium.cs 140 Active
```

Comment: `T` is a type. You see, when you use `new` keyword you create an specific instance of a class. `T` is just a type. It's not an instance. Think of it as a blueprint of a house. `T` is just a blueprint. By using `new MyClass` you built the building (an instance). You can still use the schema but you CAN'T invoke `OpenDoor()` method on schema. You have to build the house first.

Comment: Thank you, Fenio. What I thought is, if I pass an interface IPage as type, the interface implements the instance method, which each class must implement. That way, in my head, I should be able to do it. However I am not sure if it is possible this way.

Comment: Do you want to use generics only for Home Page?

Comment: no, it would be for each page in the framework, around 200 classes

Comment: Can't you make a `HomePage` and other classes generic, instead of multiplying each one with country code?

Comment: hi again, not every class has a derived class, but some of them will, in the case a derived class exists, the base class will instantiate the derived class through the use of Instance method. I am not sure if I can make that with a generic class

Comment: Depends on the methods in the derived class. Can you show us one of the Home Page classes?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Finally I fixed by using:

```
        public T InstantiatePage<T>() where T : class
    {
        // COUNTRY code as defined in
        // https://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/ISO_3166-1_alpha-2#Officially_assigned_code_elements
        var className = string.Format("{0}_{1}", typeof(T).FullName, getCulture()); 

        // T will be base class if no derived class with COUNTRY code suffix is found 
        var classType = Type.GetType(className) ?? typeof(T);

        // Instantiate the page
        var instance = Activator.CreateInstance(classType, new object[] { WebDriver });

        return (T)instance;
    }
```

I am pretty sure it could be bettered by using PageObject.PageFactory